# Why is following Coq rewrite not applying on right hand side of assumption?

Tags: coq

I have following Coq env.

```
    1 subgoals
m : nat
IHm : forall n : nat, n + n = m + m -> n = m
n : nat
H : S (n + S n) = S (m + S m)
ll := ll : forall k : nat, k + S k = S k + k
```

Doing `rewrite ll in H`, only changes the LHS `S (n + S n)` to `S (S n + n)` but not the RHS `S (m + S m)`.  `ll` should be applicable on all variables of type nat. What is wrong here?

Comment: `rewrite H` will only use one instantiation of `H`, you need to use the `!` quantifier to force more rewrites to happen. Example: `Lemma ex n m : n = m -> n + 0 = m + 0. Proof. now rewrite <- !plus_n_O. Qed.`

Comment: @ejgallego, You should have posted that as an answer!

Comment: I didn't have the time to properly write an answer, sorry. My comment is missing quite a few things including an explanation on how `rewrite` chooses the instantiation pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Emilio's comment, `rewrite H` and `rewrite H in H'` will first find an instantiation for all (dependently) quantified variables of `H`, and then replace all occurrences* of that instantiated LHS with the RHS.  I believe it finds the topmost/leftmost instantiation in the syntax tree.  So, for example, if you do this:

```
Goal forall a b, (forall x, x + 0 = x) -> (a + 0) * (a + 0) * (b + 0) = a * a * b.
  intros a b H.
  rewrite H.
```

the `rewrite H` will choose to instantiate `x` with `a`, and the resulting goal will be `a * a * (b + 0) = a * a * b`.  You can prefix the lemma with `!` (as in `rewrite !H`) to mean "rewrite everywhere, picking as many instantiations as you can", or with `?` (as in `rewrite ?H`) to mean `try rewrite !H`, i.e., you can pick multiple instantiations, and also don't fail if you can't find any.

*There's actually a bit more nuance, which is that the replacement is done in a single pass with `rewrite H` and in multiple passes with `rewrite ?H` and `rewrite !H`.  This only shows up when the first replacement(s) expose other replacement locations that weren't previously available.  This shows up, for example, if you rewrite with `a + 0 = a` in the goal `(a + 0) + 0 = a`; `rewrite H` leaves the goal `a + 0 = 0`.